# how to insert php code in one-page bootstrap template

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

actually am working on a php website, and am finished with it, and I want to make a good style to my project, I found many templates and am interested to “one-page bootstrap templates”, i have downloaded ones and don't know how to use them, I want to put my php pages in one of them but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are coding php without any framework and template engine you can combine php and html( here bootstrap template) like this :

```
<html>
    <body class="container">
        <a href=" <?php echo $link ?> "> text </a>
        <?php if $list=true ?>
            <ul>
             ...
            <ul>
       <?php endif ?>
   </body>
<html>
```

Comment: tnx :) am going to try it :)

Comment: can you please explaine more,for exemple,i have 3 pages "page1.php" "page2.php" "page3.php" how can i insert them into the templates as containers, (one page template)

Comment: I'm really surprised and amazed that the language barrier worked out for the both of you.  Kudos.

Comment: i did not get your commet @muncherelli

Comment: @BadrBarradi if you are using mvc ,just pass the params to your view(here yout template),if not , change your .html files to .php and combine html and php